# QuickSort Sortorder

Tags: delphi, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quicksort for my library based on this post [Delphi : Sorted List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485750/delphi-sorted-list)

I am not 100% sure how to implement a sort order ascending/descending into this.

Do I just switch the comperator  in `if Lo<=Hi then begin` and `until Lo>Hi;`?

I admit I don't quite understand this.

Comment: Well, better not use the code from that post at all.

Comment: Would you care to tell me why? :-)

Comment: If all you want to do is sort numeric types then it's probably fine. Would seem wasteful to have two different functions for ascending and descending as proposed by the answer you accepted. As soon as you want to sort other types then you really don't want to write a new sort function for each of them. What you need is a generic sort function.

Comment: @David Hefferman You are of course right, I was confident the OP would be able to figure out the details.

Comment: Use `System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Sort` - done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to reverse the comparison in these two lines

```
    while List[Lo] < Mid do Inc(Lo) ;
    while List[Hi] > Mid do Dec(Hi) ;
```

So make that

```
    while List[Lo] > Mid do Inc(Lo) ;
    while List[Hi] < Mid do Dec(Hi) ;
```